# No Error for unimplemented methods of Interface

Tags: java, interface

My understanding about interfaces is:

If I declare a class (which is not abstract) which implements an interface, then if I do not provide implementation of all the methods, then it must generate a compile time error, right?

The following code successfully compiles and runs.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

class DataStructure implements Iterator<Integer>{    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Fill the array with integer values and print out only
        // values of even indices
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
    }
}
```

But if I make a call to the unimplemented interface methods, then it generates a compile time error.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

class DataStructure implements Iterator<Integer>{    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Fill the array with integer values and print out only
        // values of even indices
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
        ds.next();
    }
}
```

The error log is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        The type DataStructure<Integer> must implement the inherited abstract method Iterator<Integer>.next()                                                                                           r>.next()

        at DataStructure.next(DataStructure.java:3)
        at DataStructure.main(DataStructure.java:9)
```

Is this behaviour intended, or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce - the first snippet also fails to compile. Can you share some info about your environment?

Comment: If I change the name of my class, then I get compile time error in both cases. So maybe it is refering to some other class

Comment: Voting to close as "not reproducible"

Comment: But the .java file is the only single file in my directory. Also I haven't declared it in any package. So how can this happen?

Comment: I am using VS Code. I deleted all the compiled .class files from classpath folder. Still the first one compiles and runs, but the second one doesn't.

Comment: @Mureinik I tested this on VS Code IDE on another machine. Build is failing, but if I proceed and run, the first one works fine and second one gives error.(Using Debugger for Java extension on VS code)

Comment: Perhaps VS Code is using the Eclipse compiler, which is capable of compiling erroneous code (it just replaces all bad code with `throw new Error("...")`). A benefit to this is that it allows you to test part of your project without having to have the whole thing be compilable.

Comment: @Slaw Another fun fact to add, it doesn't even report `Build failed, proceed anyway` on one of the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, when compiling via `javac` command, both fail. (as opposed to using VS code Debugger for Java extension)

Using the VS code extension, it reported `build failed`, but it allows to `Proceed anyway`, which caused this wierd behaviour.